# Typelite: Why is Dictionary<string, object> mapped to KeyValuePair and not to any or [index:string]:any

Tags: typelite

I have a class,

```
public class Instance : IResource
{
   public Dictionary<string, object> Value { get; set; }
```

and it is mapped to

```
interface Instance {
   Value: System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair[];

interface KeyValuePair {
   Key: any;
   Value: any;
}
```

I would have expected

```
interface Instance {
   Value: any;
```

or

```
interface Instance {
   Value: {[index:string]:any};
```

How can I change the generation?

Also, how can I skip the name space in the generation?

Comment: I tried ".WithConvertor<Dictionary<string,object>>(t => "any")", but the result is "Value: System.Collections.Generic.any[];" Not what I expected

Answer (score 9):

A quick and dirty workaround is to use a regex to alter output:

Using

```
<#= Regex.Replace( ts.Generate(TsGeneratorOutput.Properties)
        , @":\s*System\.Collections\.Generic\.KeyValuePair\<(?<k>[^\,]+),(?<v>[^\,]+)\>\[\];"
        , m=>": {[key: "+m.Groups["k"].Value+"]: "+m.Groups["v"].Value+"};"
        , RegexOptions.Multiline)
#>
```

Transforms a field

```
    myField: System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,OtherClass>[];
```

to

```
    myField: {[key: string]: OtherClass};
```

Comment: Awesome! Don't forget this <#@ import namespace="System.Text.RegularExpressions" #>

Answer (score 4):

Collection types (any type implementing `IEnumerable`) is converted to arrays. `Dictionary<>` implements `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<>>` and thus is converted to an array. The item-type is then expanded to its fully qualified name (FQN): `System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`.

Using Type Converters will let you change the type-name, but not the FQN. So it is only applicable to local types. In the case of dictionaries, you can't change the item type by inheritance.

You could either create a new dictionary type, without inheriting from `Dictionary<>`. Another way around this problem, is to also use Type Formatters:

```cs
ts.WithConvertor<Dictionary<string,object>>(t => {
    // Embed the real type in $
    // "System.Collections.Generic.${ [key: string]: any }$[]"
    return "${ [key: string]: any }$";
});
ts.WithFormatter((string memberTypeName, bool isMemberCollection) => {
    // Extract the content inside $
    string[] pieces = memberTypeName.Split('$');
    if (pieces.Length == 3) return pieces[1];
    // Default behaviour
    return memberTypeName + (isMemberCollection ? "[]" : "");
});
```

Comment: Note that `TypeScriptFluent.WithFormatter()` overloads are currently marked `[Obsolete]`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a more generalized (and updated) solution that builds off of Markus Jarderot's answer:

```
static void RegisterDictionaryMemberFormatter(this TsGenerator tsGenerator)
{
    tsGenerator.SetMemberTypeFormatter((tsProperty, memberTypeName) => {
        var dictionaryInterface =
            tsProperty.PropertyType.Type.GetInterface(typeof(IDictionary<,>).Name) ??
            tsProperty.PropertyType.Type.GetInterface(typeof(IDictionary).Name);

        if (dictionaryInterface != null)
        {
            return tsGenerator.GetFullyQualifiedTypeName(new TsClass(dictionaryInterface));
        }
        else
        {
            return tsGenerator.DefaultMemberTypeFormatter(tsProperty, memberTypeName);
        }
    });
}

// and if you like the fluent syntax...
static TypeScriptFluent WithDictionaryMemberFormatter(this TypeScriptFluent typeScriptFluent)
{
    typeScriptFluent.ScriptGenerator.RegisterDictionaryMemberFormatter();
    return typeScriptFluent;
}
```

Use it like this:

```
var ts = TypeLite.TypeScript.Definitions().For(typeof(SomeClass).Assembly);
ts.ScriptGenerator.RegisterDictionaryMemberFormatter();

// alternatively with fluent syntax:

var ts = TypeLite.TypeScript.Definitions()
    .For(typeof(SomeClass).Assembly)
    .WithDictionaryMemberFormatter();
```

N.B. this only fixes type signatures of properties (or fields) that have dictionary types. Also definitions for `IDictionary` are **not** automatically emitted, you'd have to add them manually:

```
declare module System.Collections.Generic {
    interface IDictionary<TKey extends String, TValue> {
        [key: string]: TValue;
    }
}
declare module System.Collections {
    interface IDictionary {
        [key: string]: any;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is awesome, but why would you choose to emit `IDictionary` at all when you could emit `{ [key: string]: string }` right in the formatter?

Comment: Thanks. This is by far the best and cleanest answer.