# TypeLite: How to convert IEnumerable<T> to any[]

Tags: c#, typescript, dto, typelite

Let's say I have the following C# class:

```
[TsClass]
public class Results<T>
{
    public IEnumerable<T> Values { get; set; }
}
```

I would like typelite to generate the following interface:

```
interface IResults {
    values: any[];
}
```

(I am appending an 'I' to the class name and lowercasing the class properties, and that works fine.)

Typelite is currently converting IEnumerable<T> to IT, which I obviously don't want. The I is being appended and the T is the generic type.

```
interface IResults {
    values: IT[];
}
```

I've looked at the following SO question which points to WithConverter or WithFormatter. 
[Typelite: Why is Dictionary<string, object> mapped to KeyValuePair and not to any or [index:string]:any](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21350501/typelite-why-is-dictionarystring-object-mapped-to-keyvaluepair-and-not-to-an)
I also looked at the typelite docs, but they don't have examples, so I'm feeling stuck. 
http://type.litesolutions.net/doc

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did get this to work, but it's definitely a hack. Funny I didn't think of it sooner.

```
<#= ts.Generate(TsGeneratorOutput.Properties).Replace("IT[]", "any[]" ) #>
```

Answer (score 1):

TypeLite has lot of extension points, but unfortunately the documentation doesn't cover them all. For this goal you can use your own `TsMemberTypeFormatter`

```
.WithMemberTypeFormatter((tsProperty, memberTypeName) => {
    var asCollection = tsProperty.PropertyType as TypeLite.TsModels.TsCollection;
    var isCollection = asCollection != null;

    if(tsProperty.GenericArguments.Count == 1 && 
       tsProperty.GenericArguments[0] is TypeLite.TsModels.TsClass && 
       ((TypeLite.TsModels.TsClass)tsProperty.GenericArguments[0]).Name =="T") {
           memberTypeName = "any";
    }

    return memberTypeName + (isCollection ? string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat("[]", asCollection.Dimension)) : "");
})
```

Comment: Great, thanks Lukas! In general, the TypeLite config feels a little verbose, but that works.